# How come my drawing code keeps resulting in fuzzy shapes?

Tags: ios, graphics, uikit

No matter what I do, I can't seem to figure out why my images keep coming out fuzzy on iOS displays.
It doesn't matter whether it's one I created in an image editor or drawing code, but I figured that code would make the issue much easier to parse. I know that if the line is 1 pixel wide, it'll appear fuzzy, but I tried multiple line width sizes with similar results. What can I do to make sure my graphics look sharp?

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(1000, 1000));
    UIBezierPath *bezier = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1000, 1000)];
    [[UIColor greenColor]set];
    [bezier fill];
    [[UIColor blackColor]set];
    bezier = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [bezier setLineWidth:1.5]; //I tried .5, 1, 1.5, & 2 with similar results
    [bezier moveToPoint:CGPointMake(450, 500)];
    [bezier addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(500, 400)];
    [bezier addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(550, 500)];
    [bezier closePath];
    [bezier stroke];

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`:

> ... is equivalent to calling the
>   `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` function with the opaque
>   parameter set to `NO` and a scale factor of `1.0`.

However, `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` defines its `scale` parameter as:

> *scale* 
>   The scale factor to apply to the bitmap. If you specify a value of `0.0`, the scale factor is set to the scale factor of the device’s main screen.

So your use of `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` is creating a context with a scale of `1.0`. That's correct for e.g. last year's iPad Mini but all retina-class devices have a 'native' scale of `2.0` — two pixels per logical point. `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` introduced the special case of `0.0` so that you don't have to mess about dealing with getting the correct number for that device for yourself (though `[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]` would be an easy way).

So switch your exiting call to `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(1000, 1000))` to:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(1000, 1000), NO, 0.0)
```

Otherwise the context you create will have a quarter as many pixels as the screen does in the corresponding amount of space.